# Upgrade Spring 4.3.3 to Spring 5.0.1 Getting Errors

Tags: spring

Can some one help me on this as I am getting this error and tried all the possible ways from my end and also tried checking with different options.

My application runs without error in Spring 4.3.3 where as when I upgrade to Spring 5.0.1 it gives the following error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controllerDependencyBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'signUpService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'signUpServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'notifyRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException.
```

All the versions and decencies are cross checked and all are correct and everything is fine, but still I get the above error. I am using Spring Security.

Comment: Post the full stack trace, and also turn on full logging and post that. You need to find out why notifyRepository isn't available as a bean.

Comment: This I got it resolved after carefully going through Respository and I am using MongoDB associated with particular table, in the repository I had a method with return type of another Bean. After removing it got resolved. The application is running, where as backend calls are not happing i.e., REST calls are not happing and showing 404 error, which are working earlier. Any idea?